# GTK widget for selecting by hue only

Tags: gtk3, vala

I've looked at the GTK ColorChooserWidget, ColorSelection, and ColorButton but none of them provide what I'm after.

When in edit mode the ColorChooserWidget seems good but there doesn't seem to be a way to hook into the event of the user moving the selector around, it just has the *color_activated* event, which seems useless when the widget is forced in to edit mode from the start:

```
ColorChooserWidget c = new ColorChooserWidget ();
c.show_editor = true;
c.set_use_alpha (false);
c.color_activated.connect ((col) => {
    stdout.printf ("Color Activated: %s\n", col.to_string ());
});
```

ColorSelection is fairly good and the *color_changed* event is ideal but there are too many options for the user. I've tried:

```
ColorSelection cs = new ColorSelection ();
cs.set_has_opacity_control (false);
cs.set_has_palette (false);
cs.color_changed.connect ( w => {
    stdout.printf ("Color changed to %s\n", w.current_rgba.to_string ());
});
```

I'd like to just have the color wheel without the other options and also be able to lock it down to only changing the hue.

Is there any way in GTK to allow a user to click and drag around a UI component that continually fires off events as the selected color is changed? Should I just create a custom widget?

Comment: ColorSelection is deprecated so avoid that, Given your (seemingly rather specific) use case your probably better off creating a custom widget

Comment: I second the previous opinion. Custom widget looks like the best solution.